# python boto3 s3 client filter subdirectories and depth

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am Trying to fetch list of subdirectories in S3 bucket without returning any filenames.

My S3 bucket have following structure.

```
s3://my-bucket/databases/mysql-<date>-<hour>    # host-2022-09-09-10
s3://my-bucket/databases/mysql-<date>-<hour>/tarfiles.tar.gz
```

I am trying to return only directory names like `mysql-<date>-<hour>`. I don't need any more sub directories or filenames inside `mysql-xx`.

As everything is stored as objects, I couldn't find any solution like setting `depth-level` etc.

my code:

```
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        my_bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)
        prefix = 'databases/mysql-'
        for item in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
            st.write(item.key)
```

Other option is to do pythonic grep/filtering the filenames. But it won't help as every request will scan all the files and return and entire list has to be filtered. Unnecessarily gets expensive.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You want to list the shared prefixes under a given prefix.

This is supported in the underlying API, though boto3's "resource" object model does not support showing prefixes for a given resource.  To accomplish this, you'll need to use the lower level "client" interface:

```python
prefix = 'databases/mysql-'
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
# Specify the prefix to scan, and the delimiter to break the prefix into
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
    for prefix in page.get("CommonPrefixes", []):
        print(prefix['Prefix'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Got some attribute error while using s3_client. 


```
AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket'

```

Comment: EDIT: 

Attribute error was due to my mistake( I left some part of the old code uncommented).

All good. !